# How to store a filename currently *.jpg reading in command rm *.jpg?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, wildcards

I want to use the filename currently used by *. How to get the name of the file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)  for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the star char `*` usually used as a wildcard in bash to select multiple files, you need to quote the filename or escape the `*` with a backslash `\`. Example:

```bsh
$ touch '*.jpg'
$ touch 'mypicture.jpg'
$ ls
'*.jpg'   mypicture.jpg
$ rm '*.jpg'
$ ls
mypicture.jpg
```

You can also use the same script with `\*.jpg` instead of `'*.jpg'`.

Comment: We've both answered from different viewpoints of what the OP has asked, as the question's a bit unclear. I think your view might actually be closer to what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Arronical I've no idea, the question is pretty unclear actually, let's wait and see ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`*.jpg` will expand to every .jpg file in the current directory. If you execute `rm *.jpg`, all of those files will be deleted. The shell expansion of the wildcard `*` does not store the results as separate variables, or give you a way to reference individual results within the expansion set.

If you wish to operate on each file matched by the wildcard expression, you may wish to use a for loop. Using a loop can assign the filename to a variable that you choose on each run of the loop. For example:

```bsh
for file in *.jpg; do
   echo "$file"
done
```

Will `echo` each of the files matched by `*.jpg`. You can of course use much more complex commands inside the loop, including other conditional statements such as `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

To show all the files indicated by `*.jpg` type:

```
ls *.jpg
```

The command `rm *.jpg` will remove all of these files.